# JPA Repository @Autowired doesn't work and returns NullPointerException

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have a simple model and repository that i want to test the "save" method:

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "TEST")
public class TestModel {

    @Id
    @NonNull
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private String id;

    @NonNull
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "testValue")
    private String testValue;

}

@Repository
public interface TestRepository extends JpaRepository<TestModel, String> {

}
```

...and on the main class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {

    @Autowired private static TestRepository testRepository;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);

        TestModel testModel = new TestModel("1", "randomValue");

        testRepository.save(testModel);

    }

}
```

When i try to use the repository to save a simple object, it gaves me NullPointerException pointing to the autowired repository.

I've used so many annotations like ComponentScan (pointing to the repository package), EntityScan (pointing to the entity package) EnabledAutoConfiguration but no one of them works for me.

I'm using Spring Boot 2.7.10, Spring Data JPA and Spring Web as dependencies in pom.xml.

Someone knows what it should be? Thanks!

Comment: You must remove static  on testrepository declaration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you cannot use `@Autowired` to inject dependencies into static fields in Spring Boot.